# GPS reliability -- how to (almost) guarantee it?

Tags: gps

**Background**

First, short history -- Samsung Galaxy Ace 2, I used it for years and GPS signal fix time is something like 2 minutes to 15 minutes (starting from town). On average. But some time ago the fix took one hour (I was long in open spaces) and on the last Saturday (2022-06-18) I waited around 2 hours and still did **not** get the fix (again open spaces, no obstacles).

I bought also two Samsung XCover 3 phones (used ones) and after buying them I checked if GPS works. GPS was fine so I thought it will be solid replacement. Yet on my previous trip (week ago) sometimes during the day it lost signal several times for few minutes. Such gaps are unusual to Ace 2, because once it is locked -- it is locked.

After returning home during the week I rechecked GPS on both of them, waiting around 15 minutes -- no signal. Next day I rechecked it -- again, no signal. This was worrying, although those short checks was within town.

So for just ended trip I took instead two XCovers, XCover + Ace2. As I wrote earlier I tested Ace2 for two hours and still nothing (I had to turn it off, because the battery is weak). On the same day XCover couldn't catch GPS for entire day+night (sic!).

On 2022-06-19 and 2022-06-20 Ace2 managed to get GPS fix within 2 minutes (starting from the forest), while XCover didn't catch at all (including nights).

As for XCover I installed some GPS status apps, and they show there are some satellites visible but not used, because "signal is too weak". The report usually goes like this -- 1 satellitte visible, 3, 5, 8, zero. And again, 1 visible, 3, 7, 9, zero. So the count is constantly cleared.

*For the record -- I didn't drop those XCovers, hit them hard, or anything, i.e. I didn't damaged them in any way.*

*To give XCover a hand I restarted it, turned on hybrid location -- GPS assisted with GSM info. I also updated AGPS data using "GPS Test" app.*

**Question**

How to improve GPS reliability to humanly possible levels? I would not like to repeat experience from my last trip.

- including buying new phone -- how to look for the best GPS receiver installed?
- using existing phone -- how to monitor the health of GPS unit, or diagnose the cause of the problems? What not to do with the phone? I put XCovers in silicone "frame" protectors (bumpers) for example. In short what can user do with existing phone to avoid losing GPS signal for good?
- how to recover from such permanent GPS problem? Could GPS receivers just die or have some expiration date?

*I am talking about normal usage, in plain, flat areas, not dungeons, not cave exploration, or something like this. And I opt for Android smartphone because of freedom (I wrote one tracking app myself) and as the Ace2 goes, no complains, I even didn't think the problems can be so severe.*

Comment: I once had the case that I could not get a fix on an Xperia XA2. Seems like the GPS chip was in an invalid state and wasn't able to recover even by reboot. The only way to fix it was to shut down the phone, wait a minute and power it on again. Also keep in mind that the signal of GPS satellites is very weak and can be interfered very easily e.g. by countries for military reasons or by people who wants to hide their position (e.g. a car thief).

Comment: @Robert, thank you. I forgot to mention I restarted the phone. For the first day it was my thinking exactly. I live in Poland and I thought maybe Russia now invading Ukraine plays with GPS satellites. But on the second day, when Ace2 got the lock this theory didn't hold.

Comment: As I wrote restarting the phone had no effect on the GPS part. Only a full shut down helped in my case. There is a small enclave Kaliningrad in the Balic Sea north of Poland and it is known that Russia disturbs GPS signals in that area. May be you are already that far away from affected area that not every device is affected?

Comment: @Robert, ah, you mean not selecting "restart" option on the phone, but instead "shutdown" and then manually starting it again? This I didn't do. As for Russia play, it would mean I need a phone with solid GPS, Ace2 is a proof it is possible, but how to know in advance if given chip is good one or not? In all tech specs I saw only generic "GPS, GLONASS, etc" merely stating what is supported.